# How to add custom strings to Kiles's »structure«-list

Tags: editors, kile, multibib

In Kile, some LaTeX commands are rendered bright red (`\section`, `\begin`, `\end`, `\cite`, …) as opposed to other commands that are displayed in brownish red (`\textbf`, `\newline`, `\enlargethispage`, …).

In Settings the bright red ones are called »structure« and can be found at Settings -> Configure Kile -> Editor -> Fonts and Colours -> Highlight Text Styles.

My Problem: I use multibib and find it very easy to spot my `\cites` as they are bright red, but very difficult to spot my `\citesrcs` as they are brownish red.

My question: Is there a way to add custom strings so that kile will see them as »structure« and brighten them up? If so, how?

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the LaTeX way of saying thank you.

Comment: And [welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: I don't get it: I closed my question with »thanks a lot«, it was not an answer. I consider it common decency to thank people for their time reading my question, even if they don't have an answer. Of course I upvote answers once their is one. I really don't get how that can be such a problem for you.

Comment: Thanks for the backticks though, didn't know that.

Comment: @Seul The way TeX-sx (and the rest of the StackExchange sites) work has a wiki-like element. So the idea is that questions 'stand on their own', which means things like 'thanks' tend to be edited out. Voting is as already mentioned the 'preferred' way to show appreciation.

Comment: @Seul: As Joseph said, it’s common sens here not to add it, for me it’s a little strange too but the „wiki style“ of this page justifies it … (PS: I used a template text, without reading it, thats why it doesn’t match here O:-))

Comment: Ok. If those are the rules, I will try to remember.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax highlighting of Kile is governed by the general syntax highlighting scheme of katepart. The relevant file for LaTeX is called latex.xml, and can be found on Unix-like systems in

- `/usr/share/apps/katepart/syntax/latex.xml` or
- `~/.kde4/share/apps/katepart/syntax/latex.xml` or
- `/opt/share/apps/katepart/syntax/latex.xml` or
- `/usr/share/kde4/apps/katepart/syntax/latex.xml`

This depends on your distribution, and operating system. Open the file in an editor, and search for `cite`. You will find a regular expression that triggers `structure` mode for those citation commands. Add `citesrc|` to this string, save, restart, done.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, it was in /usr/share/kde4/apps/katepart/syntax/latex.xml, added that to your answer, hope that's in tune with the rules...